# How to exit protractor when done

Tags: gulp, protractor

When I run [gulp-protractor](https://github.com/mllrsohn/gulp-protractor) it runs my tests fine but when done it doesn't exit

```
8 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 14.874 seconds
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 passed
[14:40:57] Finished 'test:e2e' after 16 s
```

When done, I have to hit `ctrl + c` to continue. Is it possible to tell protractor to quit when done ?

Comment: What exactly doesn't stop, are you referring to the 'WebDriver still running' or is your browser still open?

Comment: I've found the answer below :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your gulp file,

Do you have a command to exit the process at the completion of tests?

e.g.

```
gulp.task('e2e', function() {
gulp.src(['foo/bar'])
    .pipe(protractor({
        configFile: 'protractor.conf.js',
        args: ['--baseUrl', baseUrl],
        keepAlive: true
    }))
    .on('end', function() {
        console.log('E2E Testing complete');
        process.exit();
    })
    .on('error', function(error) {
        console.log('E2E Tests failed');
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

});

key line being
`process.exit()`

Comment: The real culprit should be `keepAlive: true`, which keeps protractor from closing all handles and prevens node from exiting

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this answer in the context of non-gulp protractor issues, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53521550/2738164) - the protractor.conf can be modified to use onComplete for this purpose.