# Protractor Exits with code 0 even though tests are failing

Tags: angular, npm, protractor, azure-devops

I am running protractor v4.0.9 via npm, and noticed that my build on Visual Studio Team Services does not fail even when tests are reported as failing.  Looking into this further, I introduced an error so that tests would fail and then ran them locally.  As the screenshot below shows, I have 17/17 failing tests, but the exit code is still 0, which I understand is a success.  It even says `chrome #01 passed`, which I assume is wrong.

[image: protractor passing when it should fail]

Here is my protractor config:

```
"use strict";
exports.config = {
    baseUrl: process.env.npm_package_config_baseUrl,
    framework: 'jasmine',
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },
    specs: ['test/*.spec.js'],
    rootElement: 'se-app',
    directConnect: true,
    ignoreUncaughtExceptions: false,
    onPrepare: function () {
        var globals = require('protractor');
        var browser = globals.browser;
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        var specReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

        // add jasmine spec reporter
        jasmine.getEnv().clearReporters();
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new specReporter({
            displayStacktrace: false
        }));

        var reporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new reporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            savePath: 'junit/'
        }));
    },
};
```

I checked the [documentation for the Protractor config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts) but could not see any obvious settings that would cause this to happen.  I even added in `ignoreUncaughtExceptions:false` (shown above) to be explicit but it made no difference.

Comment: what version of node are you using? I had a strange issue where I was using a newer version of node and it was where all the tests passed instantly. I had to revert to an older version of node. I found it to work with 4.2.4 , but I had to remove my node modules folder and do an npm install again.

Comment: I'm using v7.2.0.  However the build server, where I first spotted the issue, was using v5 (not sure exactly which version, as I've now updated it to v7.2.0 as well).

Comment: I realized I just said a newer version. The newer version I was using was 4.5 that was giving me the issue. One thing I use is nvm to easily switch between different versions of node. My problem wasn't exactly the same as yours but it happened to several people on my team b/c we were using version 4.5 for a different project we were working on

Comment: Your configuration looks pretty normal, I would suggest removing parts of your onPrepare or just removing your onPrepare all together and see if it returns something other than 0. I would also suggest using the latest version of Protractor: 4.0.11

Comment: Can you add the below `afterLaunch()` method to really check the exit code value
    `afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
        console.log('exit code is' + exitCode)
    },`

Comment: Also if you can provide the complete stack trace .. That would be great !

Comment: The afterLaunch function also reports an exit code of 0.  If I remove the jasmine.getEnv().clearReporters() line, it works.  But I don't want the original console reporter, only the jasmine spec reporter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.  By default, Jasmine includes the console `Reporter` and the `CompletionReporter`.  The latter is what exits the process if the tests fail.  By clearing the reporters, I was removing this reporter.

I could just remove that line, but I want to remove the console reporter so that the spec reporter and console reporter aren't both doing the same job.

So I had to add the completion reporter back in.  I'm not sure if this is the "correct" way to do it, but it works.  Here is my new onPrepare function:

```
onPrepare: function() {
    let globals = require('protractor');
    let reporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    let CompletionReporter = require('jasmine/lib/reporters/completion_reporter');
    let SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

    let browser: ProtractorBrowser = globals.browser;
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.manage().window().maximize();

    let specReporter = new SpecReporter({
        displayStacktrace: false
    });

    let junitReporter = new reporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        savePath: 'junit/'
    });

    let completionReporter = new CompletionReporter();
    completionReporter.onComplete((success: boolean) => {
        if (!success) {
            process.exit(1);
        }
    });

    // Now clear all existing reporters and add the ones I want in the order I want
    jasmine.getEnv().clearReporters();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(specReporter);
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(completionReporter);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't let protractor/Jasmine exit gracefully, so I end up with a lingering Chrome browser. So it seems as if there ought to be more graceful ways of achieving this.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Process still exits with 'Exit Status 4'

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone runs into this on Jasmine 2+, Maloric's answer won't cover you.  Instead, add the onComplete function to the protractor.conf itself:

```
...other conf...,
onComplete: function (success) {
    if (!success) {
      process.exit(1);
    }
}
```

For some reason, the default onComplete action appears to be empty, but this'll rectify it.  If you already have other onComplete actions specified, just add a `process.exit(code)` call.

Comment: Even though our tests passing / failing were working fine in terms of the process exiting with 0 or 1, we had a failure in the afterAll() which was only treated as a warning (by design, which does make sense). However we wanted this to cause the process to fail and this is the ONLY thing I found that works so far!!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `grunt-protractor-runner` module to run protractor, make sure that the option `keepAlive` in Gruntfile.js, under `protractor`.`options` is set to false.